# What is the worst case scenario if you flash a wrong custom recovery?

Tags: recovery-mode

I have a Polaroid phone which doesn't have a lot of product support and I want to port a custom recovery on it and flash it. Before I follow through with it is there any chance of hard bricking it or will the worst case be a soft brick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this problem so many times. So from the personal experience the worst case scenario is that you might soft brick your phone and would have to go stock, flashing the official firmware for your phone (and root it again).

Answer (score 0):

Jepp, my first flash was shit. So I think you don't can brick the memory flash. But when the mobile phone nothing do, you have to flash a stock firmware and root it again.  By Android 4.2 you have a counter in your phone. Eveytime when you flash a firmware, the counter set +1.

Maybe you look in the XDA Developers forum. This guys know what they do and have a great support by problems.

EDIT: My first flash was on a Galaxy S3, I don't know at the time for the sudden death. After the flash it was 'dead'. I become a new Smartphone and the have to work.

Last but not least! With the ODIN Software, be careful. Don't take the smartphone from the computer or shutdown the computer be for the flash it's complete. Whit the help from XDA Developers I build a complete custom Rom for my S3, S4 and S5.